# Priority of printing error messages in Joi

Tags: joi

I am trying to use Joi for validation and I want to customize the error messages.

Here is my code for validation:

```
count: Joi.number().error(() => 'error message').min(1).required()
```

When I test the validation, it shows " "count" must be larger than or equal to 1 " and "error message" is never shown.

I have already set abortEarly option to false but nothing changes as well.

So what is the priority of printing error messages in Joi and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try passing an instance of `Error` into the `.error()` method. For example:

```
count: Joi.number().error(new Error("Oh no!")).min(1).required()
```

However I think this will override all error messages on the `count` parameter which may or may not be what you're after. There's more detailed examples in the [Joi API docs](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.6.0/API.md#anyerrorerr).